# Automating CSS image carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 5 image carousel that works as a banner on my site. It is entirely written in CSS and works like a charm, but I think it would improve UX to have it rotate the slides on a timer.

Here is the code I have, all the slides are denoted by an `:nth-of-type` selector, so I have tried to increment the index value via `setTimeout()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x,
    $slider = $(".carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(x)");

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (x = 5) {
            x = 1
        } else {
            x + 1
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: you got the HTML and CSS?

Comment: `x = 5` defines x as 5; to compare value you need double equal sign `if (x == 5)`

Comment: `x + 1` should be `x=x+1;` or `x++;`

Comment: `x` needs to be initially defined as 1 or 0 `var x = 0, $slider ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Description

`if (x = 5)` sets `x` equal to 5, you will want to do a compare `==` or an explicit compare `===`.
`===` means it has to equal 5 and be the same type (an int).

by using `x++` we are incrementing x after we do the compare, then we are setting x = 1 if x is equal to 5.  The alternative is to set `x = 0` then use `++x` which will increment x before doing the comparison operator.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            // initialize x to be equal to 1 rather than null/undefined.
    var     x = 1,
            // you are using a variable here and it needs to be escaped.
            $slider = $(".carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(" + x + ")");

    setTimeout(function() {
        // === is an explicit compare equal operator.
        // ++ will increment the value by 1 after any operations
        //    in this case the compare operation.
        if (x++ === 5) {x = 1;}

        $("#"+x+"").prop("checked", true); 
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: If he is new, explain why he should have this solution, don't just do it for him. Otherwise how will he learn?

Comment: @BenDavison yup, was typing it up.

Comment: Thank you for the fast and informative answer, definitely taught me a couple things there. I have just tried this but now I am getting an error from the variable for $slider, jQuery 3.1.1 is stating it doesn't recognise the :nth-of-type selector and I think it is because I need to separate out the x as that is what I am trying to increment.

In VBA, I would use $slider = $(".carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(" x ")") to separate it out, taking it outside the text string, but this isn't working either?

Comment: @RichardGoodman updated, not sure if you need to be setting the value of slider in the `timeout`

Comment: thanks ABC, this helped tons. I found I was targeting the wrong thing as the whole system works off a slider. A few adjustments to the selectors above and its working great. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Thought I would show you what I finished with, as not enough people do that here! Bit of a change but just proves your lessons do help :)


    $( window ).on( "load", function() {
     var x = 1;

     setInterval(function() {
        if (x++ === 5) {x = 1;}

            $("#"+x+"").prop("checked", true);
        }, 5000);
    });

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you're considering x as string.
Check the difference between:

```
 $slider = $(".carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(x)");
```

and

```
 $slider = $(".carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type("+x+")");
```

Comment: Thanks, that has cleared that up for me too! Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that author forgot to mention that his carousel is based on the article [HOW TO: Pure CSS “carousel”](https://medium.com/@_jh3y/how-to-pure-css-carousel-ce1a8cb231c8#.a2vdxvjg2), I'll provide appropriate working solution.

I'd like to notice that solutions in other answers base on the code from the question, which even after "fixing" doesn't do anything.

## Solution

Since carousel *saves* current state in one of the `input[type=radio]` elements, all we really need to do is to determine selected `input` and select the next one (or the first one if we reached the end).

Selecting `input[type=radio]` is as simple as changing `checked` property to either `true` or `false`.

It's also worth noting that the method below doesn't care how much items is in the slider, all you need to do is call `autoSlide(element, delay)`, where `element` is any slider's container and `delay` is the time in milliseconds after which the slide will change to the next one.

```js
// Helper function for checking if Element is inside NodeList
var isInside = function (array, item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    if (array[i] == item) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

(function() {
  var nextSlide = function(slider, delay) {
    var slides = slider.querySelectorAll('.carousel__activator');
    var currentSlide = slider.querySelector('.carousel__activator:checked');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide ? currentSlide.nextElementSibling : slides[0];
    
    // If the next slide doesn't exist, go back to the beginning
    if (!isInside(slides, nextSlide)) {
      nextSlide = slides[0];
    }
    
    // Select next slide as active
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; ++i) {
      nextSlide.setAttribute('checked', false);
      slides[i].checked  = false;
    }
    nextSlide.checked = true;
    
    // Queue next slide
    autoSlide(slider, delay);
  };
  
  var autoSlide = function(slider, delay) {
    delay = parseInt(delay || 5000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      nextSlide(slider, delay);
    }, delay);
  };
  
  autoSlide(document.querySelector('.my-carousel'), 1000);
  
  // TODO: Pause when user :hover-s mouse over carousel. Otherwise, it'll be irritating.
})();
```

```css
/*/ Carousel's default CSS, nothing changes here /*/

/**
  * style variables
*/
/**
  * Control & indicator mixin
*/
.carousel {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
/**
  * Where the magic happens
  */
/**
    * Control element - right/left arrows
  */
/**
    * Element for holding slide indicators
  */
/**
    * Indicator for indicating active slide
  */
/**
    * Create rules for when slides are contained within a track
  */
}
.carousel__controls,
.carousel__activator {
  display: none;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
          transform: translateX(0%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation: carousel-show-slide 0.5s;
          animation: carousel-show-slide 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: block;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
          transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation: carousel-show-slide 0.5s;
          animation: carousel-show-slide 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
          transform: translateX(-200%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation: carousel-show-slide 0.5s;
          animation: carousel-show-slide 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(3) {
  display: block;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(3) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
          transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation: carousel-show-slide 0.5s;
          animation: carousel-show-slide 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(4) {
  display: block;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(4) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-400%);
          transform: translateX(-400%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-animation: carousel-show-slide 0.5s;
          animation: carousel-show-slide 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(5) {
  display: block;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(5) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__control {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fafafa;
  opacity: 0.35;
  outline: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
.carousel__control:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__control--backward {
  left: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
          transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.carousel__control--forward {
  right: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.carousel__indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.carousel__indicator {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.35;
  margin: 0 2.5px 0 2.5px;
}
.carousel__indicator:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.carousel__track {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
          transform: translateX(0%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
          transform: translateX(100%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(200%);
          transform: translateX(200%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(300%);
          transform: translateX(300%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(400%);
          transform: translateX(400%);
}
.carousel__slide {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
/**
  * Theming
*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #111;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.carousel-container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.my-carousel {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 30px;
}
.carousel__slide {
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fafafa;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
h2,
h3 {
  color: #fafafa;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
.carousel__indicator {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(1),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/300?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(2),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/600?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(3),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/900?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(4),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1200?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(5),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1500?random");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .carousel {
    max-width: 300px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes carousel-show-slide {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes carousel-show-slide {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Carousel's default HTML, nothing changes here -->

<div class="carousel my-carousel carousel--translate">
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="F" checked="checked"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="G"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="H"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="I"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="J"/>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="J"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="G"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="F"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="H"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="G"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="I"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="H"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="J"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="I"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="F"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__track">
      <div class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>F</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>G</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>H</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>I</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel__slide">
        <h1>J</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__indicators">
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="F"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="G"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="H"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="I"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="J"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
```